# How to filter user in LDAP PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I am using LDAP to login into the system. Currently, I can login to the system using AD account. The problem is, my system have two type of user. (Admin can read and write while the other one is Normal User which only can read). How to filter between these two user so that when Admin login, they will be brought to their HomeScreen.php and Normal User will be brought to HomeScreen2.php.

This is the coding for LDAP I've made so far (does not include the login form) :

```
set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

///config
$ldapserver = "server.name";
$ldapport    = 389;
$base_dn = "DC=xyz,DC=local";
$ldapuser  = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$ldappass  = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$ldaptree = "CN=ITInfra,OU=Groups,OU=MYABC,DC=xyz,DC=local";
$domain = '@abcd.local';

// connect 
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver,$ldapport) or die ("Could not connect to LDAP  
server.");


// Set some ldap options for talking to 
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {

        // binding to ldap server
        //$ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser.$domain, $ldappass) or die ("<b> 
 <center><font color='red'>WARNING! : ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser.$domain, $ldappass) or
 die("<b><center><font color='red'>WARNING!<br> The username or password you entered is
incorrect");
        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
        $result = @ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(ou=*)") or die ("<b> 
 <center><font color='red'>Please enter username & password");
            echo "<b><center><font color='blue'> Congratulations! $ldapuser is 
 authenticated.\n";
            header('Location: HomeScreen.php');

        } else {
            echo "LDAP bind failed...\n";
        }

}

// all done? clean up
ldap_close($ldapconn);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client successfully BINDs, the server has indicated to the client that the username and its associated password are correct - the server is able to verify that the password matches what was supplied in the BIND request. That is all that happens. If the BIND is unsuccessful, then the username and/or password is not correct. There is no distinction between LDAP objects at this point.

What is needed is a way for the client to determine of what type `username` is. There are at least two reasonable ways to do this:

- The LDAP object has an attribute indicating which user type.
- The LDAP object is a member of a group (in this case, admin or normal).

The group method is more flexible than the attribute method, since new "normal" users or new "admin" users can simply be added to the appropriate group.

For example, an admin group:

```
cn=admin users,ou=groups,o=example.com
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=admin user 1,ou=groups,o=example.com
member: cn=admin user 2,ou=groups,o=example.com
```

or a normal user group:

```
cn=normal users,ou=people,o=example.com
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=normal user 1,ou=groups,o=example.com
member: cn=normal user 2,ou=groups,o=example.com
member: cn=normal user 3,ou=groups,o=example.com
```

The client can determine to which group the `username` by searching using the appropriate search request parameters. If the `username` belongs to an admin group, then display `homescreen.php` else `homescreen2.php`.

These are two possibilities. There may be other ways, depending on your setup and the type of server (although LDAP clients must never be written as if they know what type of server they are connected to).

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. But I am confused here. Can I put two group (admin and normal user ) in one page of coding ? Then, when someone is try to login, they will be brought to respected home page according to their group which I set earlier. It this possible ?